# How to get cid of referenceAttachment in Office365 Calendar

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I created an event with a reference attachment and empty content, and try to use Graph api to get event information via [get event](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/event_get).

I found there is a hyper-link with cid in api response, and it seems that the cid belongs to reference attachment.

```
"body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<body>
                ...
                Judith has shared a OneDrive for Business file with you. To view it, click the link below. 
                ...
                <td width=\"0\" height=\"0\" style=\"display:none; visibility:hidden\">
                <a href=\"cid:3a24204a-f6fb-4719-97cc-0076701f2e62\">MyPresentation.pptx</a></td>
                ...
                </body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
}
```

However, the Microsoft Graph api document only shows how to get cid of **fileAttachment**.

Is there any way to get and set cid for **referenceAttachment** in Office365 Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, Graph have not provided get/set cid API for referenceAttachment.

You can vote up the existing feature request in [User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) or submit a new one.